# Error while using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I am trying to use FirebaseRecyclerAdapter in my chat application but it is not displaying anything.

Can anyone help?

Here are my codes: https://gist.github.com/omermujtaba/0f5dfdf0e021be87b875e6ac6b30b403

[image: This is my db structure]

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and provice a minimal example inside your question to reproduce your problem, and not the full source code

Comment: I don't know where the problem is that's why I provided the complete code of my chat activity. Please consider.

Comment: **[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49383687/how-can-i-retrieve-data-from-firebase-to-my-adapter/49384849)** is a recommended way in which you can retrieve data from a Firebase Realtime database and display it in a `RecyclerView` using `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`. Try to see the differences.

Comment: Thankyou @AlexMamo, I was doing all the adapter stuff in onStart, it needed to be done in onCreate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in my answer from the post that I gave you as an example in my comment above, the difference is that you need to move the creation of the adapter inside the `onCreate()` method and not to keep it inside the `onStart()` method. In the last one you should start listening for changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set adapter in onCreate function or try use this somewhere:

recyclerView.notifyDataSetChanged();